# phoenix + react-dom occurred error: 'process is not defined'

Tags: reactjs, elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to use react in Phoenix(elixir).
So I try this tutorial
[Phoenix v1.1.2 and React.js](https://medium.com/@diamondgfx/phoenix-v1-1-2-and-react-js-3dbd195a880a#.9rq9c2h26).

but occurred this error: 'process is not defined'

[image]

help me.

Comment: You should google it. Try something like: "react js process is not defined".

Comment: I can't find that line in the repo mentioned in that post. If this is part of your Frontend code as the filename app.js suggests, process will not be available and may not be used here as it is node.js specific and will only run on a node.js backend or inside a configuration tool that is run via node like brunch or webpack, but not in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

change to webpack from brunch.io.
all working!!
thank you!!
[using-webpack-with-phoenix-and-elixir](http://matthewlehner.net/using-webpack-with-phoenix-and-elixir/)